# Intersecting Dictionary<string, List<Anime>> on a property of Anime class

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, array-intersect

I have an object like this

```
public class Anime 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime? CreatedOn {get; set;}

}
```

Then I have a dictionary of lists like

```
Dictionary<string, List<Anime>> myLists = new Dictionary<string, List<Anime>>();
```

I am intersecting all the lists, but I would like to do the intersection on the Anime ID only but still get the result as a `List<Anime>` , Not sure how to specifically force it to do it on the ID. Here is what I have:

```
myResult.AddRange(myLists.Values.Aggregate(new HashSet<Anime>(myLists.First().Value.ToList()), (h, e) =>
                        {
                            h.IntersectWith(e);
                            return h;
                        }));
```

Is there a way to tell it to intersect on the ID property but still obtain the result as a list of Anime?  (`myResult` is a `List<Anime>`).

Comment: What do you want to have as a result? List of Anime that appears more than once in the dictionary? Or List of Anime that appears in each list in the dictionary?

Comment: List of anime  where they all have the same ID in all lists. so if i have n number of lists, ID 5 should be in all lists, then i want this Anime added to my resulting list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that lists cannot contain more than one Anime with the same Id. 
This should work:

```
var result = myLists.Values.SelectMany(p => p)
                .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
                .Where(g => g.Count() == myLists.Values.Count)
                .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of intersect on a property would be `join`:

```
myResult.AddRange(myLists.Values.Aggregate((a, l) => a.Join(l, am => am.Id, lm => lm.Id, (am, lm) => am).ToList()));
```